# Auto Populate fields on the basis of Pick List value

Tags: trigger, formula-field

I have one Pick List and two text fields. I want to auto enter text in the two fields on the basis of value selected in picklist.
For example : Values in Pick List are A and B. While filling the details if A is selected the in both text fileds   'You have selected A'  should come automatically and if I select B then 'You have selected B' . How can I do that?

Comment: This cannot be done in the Standard UI, only in Visualforce, i noticed you only tagged this question as trigger and formula-field, is a Visualforce solution an option for you?

Comment: NO, I want it to do in Standard UI.

Comment: You cannot do it in standard UI if you want it to be done as soon as user selects any of the picklist values. You can populate fields when user saves the record by using formula field or if you want it to be editable, a simple workflow field update would also work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this :

```
public class CopyPickListValues {
public string values{get; set;}
public string str1{get; set;}
public string str2{get; set;}

public CopyPickListValues(){
 values='A';
 getItems();
 showValues();
}
public list<SelectOption>getItems(){
 list<SelectOption>options=new list<SelectOption>();
 options.add(new selectOption('A','A'));
 options.add(new selectOption('B','B'));
 return options;
}
```

It is an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: User wants to do it in Standard UI, so no option for controller.